# Realm JS react-native can't create table from a large JSON from API with to-many relationship

Tags: json, react-native, realm, lodash, realm-list

In my React-Native app, using Realm DB JS, I have these three classes: TableOfProducts, Product, BarCodeProducts.

The class TableOfProducts has a list of Products and the class Product has a list of BarcodeProducts.

I model them like these:

```
export default class TableOfProductsSchema {
  static schema = {
    name: 'TabelaOfProducts',
    primaryKey: 'cdTabelaPreco',
    properties: {
      cdTabelaPreco: {type: 'int', indexed: true},
      dsTabelaPreco: 'string',
      product: 'Product[]',
      //I already tried like: product: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Product'}
    },
  };
}

export default class ProductSchema {
  static schema = {
    name: 'Product',
    primaryKey: 'tableProduct',
    properties: {
      tableProduct: {type: 'string', indexed: true},
      cdTableOfProduct: 'int',
      idProduct: 'int',
      dsProduct: 'string',
      barcodeproducts: 'ProdutoCodigosBarra[]',
      //I already tried like: barcodeproducts: {type: 'list', objectType: 'BarCodeProducts'}
    },
  };
}

export default class BarCodeProductsSchema {
  static schema = {
    name: 'BarCodeProducts',
    primaryKey: 'idProductNrItem',
    properties: {
      idProductNrItem: {type: 'string', indexed: true},
      idProduct: 'int',
      nrBarCode: 'int',
      barCodeItem: 'string',
      barCodeBox: 'string',
      qtBox: 'double',
    },
  };
}
```

And I have this code to get the JSON and create the data in my Realm DB:

```
requestTableOfPoducts = async (httpClient) => {
        let itens = null;
        await httpClient
          .get(apiConfig.url_table_products, {
            timeout: 999000,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            itens = response.data;
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));        

console.log(itens); //runs ok and show the large JSON in console so my API is receiving itens..

        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          if (itens) {
            const databaseOptions = {allSchemas};
            Realm.open(databaseOptions).then((realm) => {
              realm.write(() => {
                const resolveItens = itens.tableOfProducts.map(async (obj, k) => {
                  return realm.create('TableOfProducts', obj, true);
                });
                Promise.all(resolveItens).then(() => resolve(true));
              });
            });
          } else {
            resolve(true);
          }
        });
      };
```

The big problem here is: If I receive a small JSON data from API like just one TableOfProducts with a small list of Product, just 2 products, and two barcodes each product in the table BarCodeProducts my code runs ok and realm save all records correctly (1 record for TableOfProducts, 2 records for Product and 4 records for BarCodeProducts) but if I receive a large JSON (5MB), lots of records like 4 TableOfProducts and almost 50000 Products with more 20000 BarCodeProducts, with the same structure, I receive the error in console:

```
WARN     Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'itens.tableOfProducts.map')
```

I already tried to use ".. JSON.parse(itens) .." but I receive a message that my JSON it's already a JSON parsed.

Please, please, please.. Someone Can please help me ? What could be wrong ? There is another way ?

Comment: I already tried in my function use like this "Object.entries(itens).map" didn't work too..

Comment: This wouldn't fix the underlying problem, but could you batch the transactions so that you're only doing a certain number per second?

Comment: Thanks Abe, I tried didn't work, I tried "_.each" "_.map" from lodash and didn't work too. I don't know why with a small data works and a large data doesn't.

Comment: Do you know which record causes the problem, or is it never the same?

Comment: Abe, thanks again, it's always the same problem, I think that's because the JSON is too big 5mb when I try to read a small amount of data it works fine.